# Using like to get multiple values in query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this query.

```sql
select * from Table1 where ID like @id
```

Which is called as follows:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString());
```

This is my whole code.

```
con = new SqlConnect();
con.SqlQuery("Select * from EmployeeDeduct where EmployeeeID = @empID");
con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", lblEmpID.Text);
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
con.cmd.Connection.Close();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; g++)
    {
        con = new SqlConnect();
        con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo");
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds2);
        con.cmd.Connection.Close();
        if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
            {

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[g].ItemArray[0].ToString() == ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString())
                {
                    //LvDeductions.Items[j].Checked = true;
                    con = new SqlConnect();
                    con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo where DeductID like @id");
                    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString());
                    ListViewDed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am only getting one row instead of 3. Any thoughts please? Please see image

[image]

Here is the working code so far

```
con = new SqlConnect();
con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo");
ListViewDed();
con = new SqlConnect();
con.SqlQuery("Select * from EmployeeDeduct where EmployeeeID = @empID");
con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", lblEmpID.Text);
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
con.cmd.Connection.Close();
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int g = 0; g < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; g++)
    {
        con = new SqlConnect();
        con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo");
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(con.cmd);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds2);
        con.cmd.Connection.Close();
        if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
            {

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[g].ItemArray[0].ToString() == ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString())
                {
                    LvDeductions.Items[j].Checked = true;
                    //con = new SqlConnect();
                    //con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo where DeductID like @id");
                    //con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString());
                    //ListViewDed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please see image here

[image]

I want to change the code:

```
// LvDeductions.Items[j].Checked = true;
```

using this

```
// con = new SqlConnect();
// con.SqlQuery("Select * from DeductionInfo where DeductID like @id");
// con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString());
// ListViewDed();"
```

So I can remove the checkbox.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215495/discussion-on-question-by-james-dean-using-like-to-get-multiple-values-in-query).

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString());
```

The code `ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString()` must include the SQL Like Wildcards `%` or `_`

Comment: Hi I tried ds2.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray[6].ToString()+"%" and it show one row and i tried underscore on first click nothing shows up and I click another name and got error which is 'There is no row at position 0.'

Comment: List<string> data = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow rr in dt.Rows)
            {
                data.Add(rr.Field<string>(0));
            }
            var joined = string.Join<string>(",", data.ToArray());
            MessageBox.Show(joined);

I was inspired of that, however I dont know the code how to split them to read as one string to use in Wildcard query "IN"

Answer (score 0):

OMG!!!

I managed to solved my problem after several hours of searching. I kept the code that way it was working. I just disabled the checkboxes in my ListView and added this code to filter all items that are unchecked and remove it using this code.

```
foreach (ListViewItem Item in LvDeductions.Items)
    {
            if (!Item.Checked)
            {
                if (LvDeductions.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    ListViewItem foundItem = LvDeductions.FindItemWithText(Item.Text, false, 0, true);
                    if (foundItem != null)
                    {
                        LvDeductions.Items.Remove(foundItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LvDeductions.Items.Remove(foundItem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks to this him https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1106570/Remove-unchecked-items-from-listview